Build only changed projects in a .net core solution, in azure devops pipeline
Scenario

I have three running projects in a .NET Core 7 solution
I have a build yaml pipeline (in Azure Devops), for continuous integration, which detects any changes in the staging branch, and build the artifact, which then consumed by the release pipeline for continuous deployment to respective Azure App services, connected via service connection.
However, if I change only in one project, then I don't want other two unchanged projects to build and deploy, because it is time expensive, and consumes my free Microsoft hosted machine time.

For the build pipeline I have the typical workflow:

Setting trigger and vmImage
Installing .net 7, and NuGetToolInstaller
Building the solution, and Publishing the Artifacts

Artifacts are in the drop/{{ProjectName}}.zip (3 files under drop folder)
And, for the Release pipeline:

Trigger
And, then 3 task, for the webapps deployment based on Service connection and file under drop folder.

What I would like to do, is only build and deploy, only those projects, which got changed, for the reasons that are mentioned above.
I think, this is a common scenario for big solution (containing 100s of projects), because some projects might never get changed (because they are old, or legacy), help would be appreciated, because I couldn't able to find any solution for this case scenario.
Thanks

A big solution containing 100s of projects is not a good idea, at least in my opinion. Alvin Zhao's suggestion might work, but in the medium or long term the solution should be broken down into smaller ones, to make things more manageable.

Hi @DharmendraSinsinwar, Good day to you. Have you got a chance to check my answer below to use git diff command to sort out the changed projects? Thx for your time and sharing.

Update
Based on the further discussions, you may use the git diff command to detect the changed files under certain paths and determine the target projects to build by adding the target arument to the dotnet build command.
Here is a sample YAML pipeline for your reference with the PowerShell script to detect the changed files by comparing the two commits $(Build.SourceVersion)^ and $(Build.SourceVersion). It is NOT reliable when the pipeline was triggered by a push (such as a merge commit by a PR) that included multiple commits. Therefore, if possbile, isolated repos or at least seperate pipelines are still recommended.
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0 # Change default fetchDepth: 1 to make sure git diff command work

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Build.SourceVersion is $(Build.SourceVersion)"
    $targetProj = @()

    # Check if there are changes in WebApp1
    if (git diff --name-only $(Build.SourceVersion)^ $(Build.SourceVersion) -- WebApp1) {
        Write-Host "Changes detected in WebApp1"
        $targetProj += "WebApp1"
    }

    # Check if there are changes in WebApp2
    if (git diff --name-only $(Build.SourceVersion)^ $(Build.SourceVersion) -- WebApp2) {
        Write-Host "Changes detected in WebApp2"
        $targetProj += "WebApp2"
    }

    # Check if there are changes in WebApp3
    if (git diff --name-only $(Build.SourceVersion)^ $(Build.SourceVersion) -- WebApp3) {
        Write-Host "Changes detected in WebApp3"
        $targetProj += "WebApp3"
    }

    # Join the project names with a semicolon
    $targetProjString = $targetProj -join ';'
    Write-Host "Target projects to build: $targetProjString"

    # Set an output variable to pass to the next task
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TargetProjects]$targetProjString"
  displayName: 'Determine Target Projects to Build'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    arguments: '-t:$(TargetProjects)'
  displayName: 'Build Target Projects'
  condition: ne(variables['TargetProjects'], '')



If you would expect the pipeline to get triggered upon the changes of certain projects rather than any project associated to the solution, the path filter in the trigger section of a YAML pipeline is probably the easiest way.
For this, you may try to add paths section in the YAML definition file from your staging branch, to include the path(s) to the expected project(s) or exclude the path(s) to the unexpected project(s); that can control whether the changes/commits pushed to the files under those paths will trigger the build pipeline or not.

Ok, thanks, that's what I thought.
However, by using path, as a trigger, I can run the pipeline based on the changed project/s,
but how will it only build and deploy only the changed project/s.
I am more focusing, on the after trigger operation.

For the work after the trigger, would you consider using different pipelines to build different projects? Since they will be deployed to different app services, it is also rational to use different pipelines, right? You can also create the YAML definition files in different paths for example in each project directory.

So, you are saying to use different yml pipelines for different projects, like pipelineA.yml for projectA, pipelineB.yml for projectB and pipelineC.yml for projectC.
However, the changes could include all the projects, a combination of two, or single one.

Yes I understand. So the changes including more than one projects will respectively trigger their own pipelines. Do you mean the changes in the projects can affect one another, or say if not building the changed projects in one single run, it will fail?

Hi @DharmendraSinsinwar, I have updated my answer with a possible workaround for your reference. Hope the information may help resolve you concerns in this post. Thx.
